# Does iOS have a firewall?

Tags: iphone, ios, network, security, firewall

Does iOS support a built-in firewall like macOS does? I don't see anything about it in Settings.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Would be nice to have a Firewall enabled when using a public wifi hot spot, etc.

Comment: Again, why? Apps are sandboxed. Un-needed ports are blocked. What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just an extra layer of security, having a iOS device saying I am here and I have ports open does not seem wise

Comment: I've had folks at DC612 (the local Defcon SIG) try various scanning tools against my iPhone and they haven't come up with anything useful. Not a definitive answer I realize, but it seems to me you're chasing dragons. Best of luck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Page 27 of the September 2015 [iOS Security White Paper](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) states that there is not a firewall on iOS.

> On other platforms, firewall software is needed to protect open communication ports against intrusion. Because iOS achieves a reduced attack surface by limiting listening ports and removing unnecessary network utilities such as telnet, shells, or a web server, no additional firewall software is needed on iOS devices.

Comment: How did you find out about "All ports are dynamically blocked on iOS to incoming traffic until an app needs specific access"

Answer (score 0):

When you have jail broken your iPhone/iPod/iPad you can download a firewall setting in cydia

You can find an article about it here:

http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/02/17/firewall-ip-2-0-released-in-cydia-a-security-center-for-the-iphone/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, Xcodeuser!! Thanks for posting an answer. Can you please add a little more information, such as a link to the firewall setting tweak? Thanks!