# No Jailbreak Firewall for iOS (iPhone) for iOS 7

Tags: ios, jailbreak, firewall

Is there a non jailbreak firewall for the iPhone or is there some way to set one up, somehow?

Comment: No. This still applies to iOS 7: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48060/do-ios-5-1-devices-have-a-firewall

Answer (score 0):

As of now, and for the foreseeable future, it is not possible for 3rd party developers to create a firewall app.

Apple need to do it, and my personal guess is they will not, since even for the mac os x the firewall "configuration" the os itself provides, is minimal.

I think Apple is still in the mindset that you can build a bulletproof ecosystem of OS and apps (which IMHO very very very naive).

I wish there was a version of little snitch that you could run on iphone. I would jailbreak my devices in an instant if there was one.

Comment: There is an application similar to LittleSnitch for jailbroken iOS: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45022/18387

Comment: Also, please see my answer here that gives Apple's official explanation for not needing a firewall: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/48109/18387

Answer (score 0):

In essential, it **could** be possible, with a jailbroken device.

One would need clang or gcc (compilers) that actually **work.**

Then, at that point, since iOS basically runs the same UNIX shell as a Mac, they could compile a firewall, and it could work.

I can't try this, my compiler doesn't work for big scripts.

Comment: Here's some additional information on this subject: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45022/18387