# Why can't I access HTTPS sites through my iPhone's hotspot?

Tags: iphone, ssh, firewall

I can access HTTP and HTTPS sites from the iPhone without any problems. However, when I use the iPhone as a hotspot and connect my laptop to the it, I can't access HTTPS sites from the laptop.

It's almost as if there's a firewall on the iPhone, but [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48060/does-ios-have-a-firewall) says that there isn't.

What else could it be?

Comment: Can you access https sites from your laptop when you're connected elsewhere?

Comment: @Little.Eden: Yes, I can.